# Unexpected output in rails when using scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Environment - Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.3

Trying to play with scopes and created one that will return true or false for the user.superuser of the current_user, from inside the non-User Model/Controller. I am getting the expected output when current_user.superuser = true but false just goes out left field.

Breakdown:

appliance.rb (model)

```
scope :superuser, ->(user) { user.superuser ? true : false }
```

appliance_controller.rb

```
def list
  @appliances = Appliance.all.order(:idtag)
  @users = User.all
end
```

list.html.haml

```
%h5
  = "Is the user a superuser? #{Appliance.superuser(current_user).to_s}"
```

Rails console for when querying a user that has the superuser attribute set to true

```
irb(main):006:0* current_user = User.first   User Load ... #<User id: 3, superuser: true>
```

> irb(main):007:0> Appliance.superuser(current_user)
>
> => true

Rails console for when querying a user that has the superuser attribute set to false

```
irb(main):008:0> current_user = User.last User Load # User id: 6, superuser: false>
```

> irb(main):010:0* Appliance.superuser(current_user)
>
> Appliance Load (4.1ms)  SELECT "appliances".* FROM "appliances"
>
> =>#ActiveRecord::Relation [#Appliance id:1, ... updated_at: "...">, #Appliance id:2, ... updated_at: "...">]>

Basically it's dumping Appliance.all and returns an ActiveRecord_relation instead of false. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the rails [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) :

> Scope Adds a class method for retrieving and querying objects. The method is intended to return an ActiveRecord::Relation object, which is composable with other scopes. If it returns nil or false, an all scope is returned instead.

So this is not unexpected, rather a exact expected behavior. your scope returns `false`, it applies `all` scope and dumps all of the `Appliance` records, which are `activerecord relation` objects, as stated in api.

Comment: Thanks I remember reading that but I guess I did not fully understand it.

Comment: No problem. sometimes, happen with me too.